# List of mixed types in Dart

Tags: list, dart

This *compiles* in Dart:

```dart
var  data = ["abcd", 34, "ef", false];
int n = data[1];
print(n*2); // -> 68
```

I thought that list elements should be all of same type. And there is not implicit conversion  from int to string or from bool to string in A):

```dart
 print(data[1] is int);    // -> true
 print(data[3] is bool);   // -> true
 print(data[1] is String); // -> false
```

**EDIT**: as Mattia pointed out the real error in the following lines is not related to swapping elements in the list initializatione but to copy/paste from A) to B) leaving the same index ([1])

And this does ***not*** compile ("abcd" swapped with 34):

```dart
var  data = [34, "abcd", "ef", false]; // -> type error
int n = data[1]; //EDIT: this is a non sense, should be data[0] (no error generated)
print(n*2);
```

[Reproducible DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/a83ce59618c1323235b1062f00f84282)

Why? Some sort of substitution principle at work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want list to accept only one type you need to add a `generic type` for example:

```dart
var  data = <int>["abcd", 34, "ef", false]; // -> Error
```

by default if you don't add one the "most common type" (in this case Object) will be used and it will accept all variable types.

The second example does compile but gives a run-time error because `data[1]` is not an `int` but a `String`

Comment: Edited my post after Mattia answer to point out the real compile error cause. Thank you Mattia. Now I understand much better the flexibility of _dynamic_: with it (which I used without realizing it) we could mix everything such as : `var mixed = [new List<int>(3), "hello", 67, 3.14];
 (mixed[0] as List<int>)[0] = 3434;
 print( (mixed[0] as List<int>)[0]);  // -> 3434`